# Сортировка в односвязном списке

Tags: delphi, сортировка, список

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь реализовать сортировку выборкой по фамилии. Проблема в том, что после выполнения программа просто вылетает. Пробовал запускать поэтапно: вроде бы все выполняется, но потом все равно вылетает. (Пытаюсь перезаписывать не ссылки, а просто данные (val), оставляя ссылки, как есть)

```
 type
  fullname = record
    surname:string;
    name:   string;
    midname:string;
  end;
type
  fulldate = record
    day:  integer;
    month:integer;
    year: integer;
  end;
type
  data = record
    fio:   fullname;
    adress:string;
    born:  fulldate;
    brain: double;
  end;
type
  pPerson = ^person;
  person = record
    val:data;
    next: pPerson;
  end;
var
  student:data;
  head:pPerson;
  x,z:integer; 
///////////////////////////////////

Procedure makeSort(var head:pPerson);
var
  pt,pt1,lastPt:pPerson;
  tmp:person;                //type of list
begin
  pt:=head;
  while pt<> nil do          //search last link
  begin
    if pt^.next=nil then
    begin
      lastPt:=pt;
    end;
    pt:=pt^.next;
  end;                       // end of SLL

  pt:=head;
  while pt<> lastPt do
  begin
    pt1:=pt;
    while pt1^.next <> nil do
    begin
      if pt^.val.fio.surname>pt1^.next.val.fio.surname then
      begin
        tmp.val:= pt1^.next.val;
        pt1^.next.val:=pt^.val;
        pt^.val:=tmp.val;
      end;
      pt1:=pt1^.next;
    end;
    pt:=pt^.next;
  end;
end;
//...
```

Comment: Если `head = nil`, то в `lastPt` будет неизвестно что и `pt` никогда не будет равен `lastPt`. И на `while pt1^.next` должно вылетать AV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type
  TFullname = record
    surname:  string;
    name:     string;
    midname:  string;
  end;

  TFulldate = record
    day:    integer;
    month:  integer;
    year:   integer;
  end;

  TData = record
    fio:    TFullname;
    adress: string;
    born:   TFulldate;
    brain:  double;
  end;

  PTPerson = ^TPerson;
  TPerson = record
    val: TData;
    next: PTPerson;
  end;

var
  head: PTPerson;

procedure makeSort(head: PTPerson);
var
  pCurrentPerson,
  TmpValue: TData;
begin
  pCurrentPerson := head;
  while Assigned(pCurrentPerson)
    and Assigned(pCurrentPerson^.next)
  do
  begin
    if pCurrentPerson^.val.fio.surname > pCurrentPerson^.next^.val.fio.surname then
    begin
      TmpValue := pCurrentPerson^.next^.val;
      pCurrentPerson^.next^.val := pCurrentPerson^.val;
      pCurrentPerson^.val := TmpValue;
    end;
    pCurrentPerson := pCurrentPerson^.next;
  end;
end;
```

Сортирует и не падает.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, одна помарочка: pCurrentPerson должно быть pCurrentPerson:PTPerson, мы же потом к head'у его приравниваем. А так: попробовал копипастнуть код, всё равно рез-тат тот же -  просто вылетает. Может быть, идея по сути своей  неверная и надо с ссылками перезаписывать?

Comment: И еще: в общем, стыдно признаться, но, оказывается, и мой код работает (ваш, конечно, более филигранный), а суть вылета в том, что я когда менюшку переделывал, то забыл изменить "Until x = 5" на другое значение, где 5  - функция сортировки, т.е. оно делало сорт, потом переходило на until и завершало работу. В общем, стыдпозор)

Comment: @111xbot111, все верно `pCurrentPerson: PTPerson;`, навеное, когда копировал сюда, где-то промазал.
Ну ошибки у всех бывают, как видишь :) Изучай возможности отладчика.